# URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: ".P"

Tags: java

How do I properly decode the string which contains % in Java
When I use `URLDecoder.decode()` i am getting the following error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: ".P"
    at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(Unknown Source)
```

Is there anyway to bypass this special consideration. Or any idea on how to use % character?

Comment: It sounds like the string you are decoding was never encoded properly. That's the problem

Comment: This is how android does URL encoding.

Answer (score 19):

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11257540/1283847) provided by Mark Byers will work just fine if there're only `%` chars that need to be escaped but will fail if url contains percent-encoded chars. To avoid this there's a little bit more work needed.

In percent-encoding (url-encoding) *only* [reserved](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-12) and [unreserved](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-13) chars won't be percent-encoded.

```
Reserved chars:
╔═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╗
║ ! ║ # ║ $ ║ & ║ ' ║ ( ║ ) ║ * ║ + ║ , ║ / ║ : ║ ; ║ = ║ ? ║ @ ║ [ ║ ] ║
╚═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╝

Unreserved chars:
╔═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╗
║ A ║ B ║ C ║ D ║ E ║ F ║ G ║ H ║ I ║ J ║ K ║ L ║ M ║ N ║ O ║ P ║ Q ║ R ║
╚═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╝
╔═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╗
║ S ║ T ║ U ║ V ║ W ║ X ║ Y ║ Z ║ a ║ b ║ c ║ d ║ e ║ f ║ g ║ h ║ i ║ j ║
╚═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╝
╔═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╗
║ k ║ l ║ m ║ n ║ o ║ p ║ q ║ r ║ s ║ t ║ u ║ v ║ w ║ x ║ y ║ z ║
╚═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╝
╔═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╗
║ 0 ║ 1 ║ 2 ║ 3 ║ 4 ║ 5 ║ 6 ║ 7 ║ 8 ║ 9 ║ - ║ _ ║ . ║ ~ ║
╚═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╝
```

According to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) percent-encoded character has following format: `% + hex`. So if you want to properly escape url that has unescaped `%` chars without breaking the whole url before actually decoding it, you need to replace only those `%` signs that are not followed by hex.

Finding substring that violates some pattern is pretty easy task with regex. In this case pattern will look like this:

```
%(?![0-9a-fA-F]{2})
```

---

[Sample:](http://ideone.com/n2Amyu)

```
class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String url = "http://example.com/test?q=%.P%20some%20other%20Text";
        url = url.replaceAll("%(?![0-9a-fA-F]{2})", "%25");
        System.out.println(url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Whoever created the URL should have [percent encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the `%` by writing `%25`.

**Example invalid URL**

```
http://example.com/test?q=%.P
```

**Example valid URL**

```
http://example.com/test?q=%25.P
```

Comment: I think it does. a string with %hex-escaped characters is invalid if there's a bare % so the % needs to be encoded.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `%` with `%25` before call `URLDecoder.decode`.